# Как сделать что бы контент не смещался

Tags: html, css

Фильмы не встают друг под друга а если это сделать то слетает поисковая строка и все что за ней вот коды.
Html и css.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: 60%;
  color: 8px;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 250% 'century gothic, arial';
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.main,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em text-decoration: none;
}

{}

.logo h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999
}

.menubar {
  width: 900px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_container {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  text-align: left;
  width: 620px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}

.content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: #a8aa94;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.footer a {
  color: #a8aa94;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="description" content="КиноМания - это портал о кино">
  <meta name="keyworlds" content="фильмы, фильмы онлайн, hd" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">КиноМания</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - наша страсть</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p1><big><h1>Новые фильмы</h1></big></p1>
        <div class="films_block"></div>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/matrix.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/max.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/inter.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/cloud.png"></a>
      </div>
      <p1><big><h1>Новые фильмы</h1></big></p1>
      <div class="films_block"></div>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/breakingbad.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/silicon.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/dead.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/xfiles.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site_content">
    <div class="sidebar_container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Поиск</h2>
        <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
          <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Вход</h2>
        <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
          <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="Логин" />
          <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="Пароль" />
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Вход" />
          <div class="lables_passreg_text">
            <span><a href="#">Забыли пароль?</a></span> | <span><a href="#">Регестрация</a></span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Новости</h2>
        <span>01.07.2018</span>
        <p>Мы запустили расширенный поиск</p>
        <a href="#">читать</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Интерстеллар</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.1</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Матрица</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.0</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Безумный Макс</a><span class="rating_sidebar">7.5</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Облачный Атлас</a><span class="rating_sidebar">7.4</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<div class="footer">
  <p>
    <a href="#">Главная</a> |
    <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
    <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
    <a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a> |
    <a href="#">Контакты</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    wh-db.com 2018
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

набросок на скорую руку.

**HTML**

в первую очередь надо добавить в `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

оптимизация под мобильные устройства [Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

`html`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <meta name="description" content="КиноМания - это портал о кино">
      <meta name="keyworlds" content="фильмы, фильмы онлайн, hd" />

    <style>
      ....
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <div class="logo_text">
            <h1><a href="/">КиноМания</a></h1>
            <h2>Кино - наша страсть</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menubar">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="films_block">
            <h2>Новые фильмы</h2>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/fff766/fff.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/74b9f1/fff.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/6a737c/fff.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/ff99cc/fff.png"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="films_block">
            <h2>Новые фильмы</h2>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/cc33ff/fff.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/66ff99/fff.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000/fff.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/a51e65/fff.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site_content">
          <div class="sidebar_container">
            <div class="sidebar">
              <h2>Поиск</h2>
              <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
                <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти" />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
              <h2>Вход</h2>
              <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
                <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="Логин" />
                <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="Пароль" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Вход" />
                <div class="lables_passreg_text">
                  <span><a href="#">Забыли пароль?</a></span> | <span><a href="#">Регестрация</a></span>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
              <h2>Новости</h2>
              <span>01.07.2018</span>
              <p>Мы запустили расширенный поиск</p>
              <a href="#">читать</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
              <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Интерстеллар</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.1</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Матрица</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.0</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Безумный Макс</a><span class="rating_sidebar">7.5</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Облачный Атлас</a><span class="rating_sidebar">7.4</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>
          <a href="#">Главная</a> |
          <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
          <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
          <a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a> |
          <a href="#">Контакты</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          wh-db.com 2018
        </p>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
*,
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
        margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
}

html,body{
  min-height:100vh;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: 60%;
  color: 8px;
}

img {
  border:0;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 250% 'century gothic, arial';
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px
}
ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
}
.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}
.main,
.logo,
.menubar,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}
.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}
.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em text-decoration: none;
}
.logo h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999
}
.menubar {
  width: 900px;
  height: 46px;
}
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0 auto;
  line-height:46px;
  text-align:center;
}
ul.menu li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}
ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 13px 35px 13px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}
ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.site_content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:250px;
  text-align:right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:20px 0 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
.sidebar_container {
  text-align:left;
  width: 224px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}
.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.sidebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100% - 260px);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin:20px auto 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
  color: #136cb2;
}
.content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.films_block{
  padding-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.films_block a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  max-width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin:0 4px 8px;
}
.films_block img {
  max-width:100%;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 132px;
  padding: 28px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: #a8aa94;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}
.footer a {
  color: #a8aa94;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо фильмы встали